# use WebSocket in react js. in case of cross-domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket

I use [WebSocket](https://github.com/websockets/ws) in react Js. To establish a WebSocket connection, the client sends a WebSocket handshake request, for which the server returns a WebSocket handshake response。React Js use Method Fetch to send the request. so a cross-domain error occurs.
 server sample code :

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
    port: 10000
});
let num = 1;
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
    });
    setInterval(function () {
        console.log(num);
        ws.send(num);
        num = num + 1;
    }, 500);
});
```

client sample code:

```
type State = {
    data: string
};
class App extends Component {
    state: State;
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('开始建立Web Socket');
        const webSocket = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:10000');
        webSocket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
            console.log('建立连接');
        });
        webSocket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
            console.log('Message from server ', event.data);
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <div className="App-header">
                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo"/>
                <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
            </div>
            <p className="App-intro">
                To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
            </p>
          </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

So how to solve the cross-domain problem during  Web Socket establishment.

Comment: Really?? CORS for `ws` ? can you show your exact error ?

Comment: This is a server side issue, you needs to allow CORS on your server.

Comment: when I use ''ws://echo.websocket.org/" as the web socket server, I got an error  as follow,
localhost/:1 Fetch API cannot load http://echo.websocket.org/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

but I tried them in chrome console, They both executed successfully.

Comment: when I use ''ws://echo.websocket.org/" as the web socket server, I got a a cross domain problem.

but I tried them in chrome console, They both executed successfully.